# Methods of Fragment class in android not getting called

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I am a beginner for android and in my app I have to show SlidingPaneLayout at right side.

So far everything is OK.

But when I tap on SlidingPaneLayout of any row I want to reload Listview for this I wrote below code.

But here Listview is reloading by default, but when I tap on SlidingPaneLayout it's not reloading.

Below lines are not executing when I call getAllTips() method from MainActivity.

```
if (friendArrayList.size() != 0) {            
     Log.d("=======>" ," data Available");         ˚   
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
    }else{          
    Log.d("=======>" ,"No data Available");         
    }
```

### ListViewFragment:-

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncTaskClass.BackGroundServiceCall {

    private ArrayList<MyTripBean> friendArrayList;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout,container,false);

        ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

        //set ListView header:-
        inflater =  getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_listview,listView,false);
        listView.addHeaderView(header);

        //adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_listview, friendArrayList);

        friendArrayList =  new ArrayList<MyTripBean>();

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item, friendArrayList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        getAllTips(getActivity(),9); //Getting friendArrayList data from Services

        return view;
    }

    // get all trips of the User
    public void getAllTips(Activity activity,int tripstatus) {

        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("TripStatus", tripstatus);
            json.put("medicaidId", "104584743999");

            if (CommonUtilities.isNetWorkStateAvailble(activity)) {

                AsyncTaskClass task = new AsyncTaskClass(this, activity,
                        json);
                task.execute(ServiceUrl.GET_ALL_TRIPS, "1",
                        "Token");

            } else {
                Log.d("==========>", "There is Network Error");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doPostExecute(StatusObject statusObject) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (statusObject != null) {

            if (statusObject.getResponseCode() == 401) {
                Log.d("==========>", "Session Has been Expired");

            } else if (statusObject.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                handleResponseData(statusObject.getMessage());

            } else {
                Log.d("==========>", "Server not responding. Please try again later.");
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("==========>", "Server not responding. Please try again later.");
        }
    }

    // handle the response
    public void handleResponseData(String result) {

        Log.d("Final Json==========>", result);

        try {
            Object json = new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
            if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
                // you have an object

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                if (jsonObject.has("Error")) {

                    if (jsonObject.getString("Error").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

                        if (jsonObject.has("message")) {

                            Log.d("==========>", "there is erorr mesage coming from server");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
                // you have an array
                handleTripsResponse(result);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // handle the json array data
    public void handleTripsResponse(String result) {

        try {

            Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyTripBean>>() {
            }.getType();

            ArrayList<MyTripBean>  newListData = new Gson().fromJson(result, type);
            friendArrayList.addAll(newListData);

            if (friendArrayList.size() != 0) {
                Log.d("=======>" ," data Available");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                Log.d("=======>" ,"No data Available");
            }

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {

        }
    }
}
```

### MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SlidingPaneLayout mSlidingPanel;
    ListView mMenuList;

    String [] MenuTitles = new String[]{"First Item","Second Item","Third Item","Fourth Item"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        mMenuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                ListViewFragment fragment1 = new ListViewFragment();
                fragment1.getAllTips(MainActivity.this,8);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I can't see the code you say *not executing* in `getAllTips()` method. Can you show all code of getAllTips()?

Comment: if (friendArrayList.size() != 0) {
                Log.d("=======>" ," data Available");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                Log.d("=======>" ,"No data Available");
            }

Comment: this if and else blocks are not executing when i call getAllTips() method from my MainActivity

Comment: Yeah man I understood from your question. The code you say **not executing**, I cannot see it in `ListViewFragment`'s `getAppTips()` method. If that code doesn't exist in the method, how compiler will execute it?

Comment: public void getAllTips(Activity activity,int tripstatus) {

Comment: this is exist in LiustviewFragment

Comment: m checking your code. jst to cross verify I am asnking this that where you have initialized mMenuList with the listvView in activity?

Comment: yes, sort of. tell me Krish.

Comment: can i send my sample app please see once where is mistack happaning please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109497/discussion-between-krish-and-srv-sud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine. OnItemClickListeners looks fine for the listview and will work correctly.
I doubt if you are getting exception in method handleTripsResponse(). please try printing log in the catch block of this method. then you will come to know the exception and how to resolve it.

Also in your MainActivity, in onItemClickListener, do not create a new instance of the ListViewFragment, instead use the instance of fragment which you attached in fragment transaction.

```
 ListViewFragment fragment1 = new ListViewFragment();
            fragment1.getAllTips(MainActivity.this,8);
```